# Sending an Empty String as RequestBody not hitting the Rest endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, request, jackson

I m trying to write a unitTest for an endpoint.

This endpoint should take a json object as follow

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test")
public String endPoint(@RequestBody String obj) {

        try {
          JSONObject inputJsonObject = new JSONObject(individualJson);
        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                    throw new MyException("JSONObject not valid");
        }
 ......
 }
```

in my unit test I m trying to send an empty string and I m expecting to have a JSONException

```
mvc.perform(post(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(""))
                .andReturn().getResponse();
```

however this my post is not hiting my endpoint... it is like it is not able to evaluate an empty String as a String : "" is not hitting the endpoint however 
" " (with a space) is hitting the endpoint ...

Here is the exception returned by the call :

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Required request body is missing: public 
>   com.ba.mypackage.MyController.endPoint(java.lang.String)

How may I access the endpoint by passing an empty string "" ?

Comment: And you aren't seeing any exception on server log ?

Comment: yes, I updated my post to put the exception

Comment: @tima and why would an empty string not be a meaningful object?

Comment: @tima endpoint is not expecting valid JSON but a string - "@RequestBody String obj". for invalid JSON, a `MyException` would be thrown

Comment: @eis i missed that...

Answer (score 2):

Because empty string is not a valid String and treated similar to Null.

However if you just want to hit the controller and not interested in the empty strings value inside of controller, just mark the parameter as optional.

```
public String endPoint(@RequestBody(required = false) String obj) {
```

Comment: thx! however this make my endpoint receive null.. I want that it receive empty String ""

Comment: empty string is certainly a valid String.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, since sending an empty string as body is the same thing as not sending a body in this context, and not sending a body is disallowed by `@RequestBody` annotation, since default value for its `required` attribute is `true`.

Sending an empty string as body is the same thing as not sending a body because in HTTP, a POST request has a header section and body section separated by CRLF, and separating CRLF is required both when having a body and not having it. This is how it is defined in HTTP specification, see https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html for details:

> **5 Request**
>
> A request message from a client to a server includes, within the first line of that message, the method to be applied to the resource, the identifier of the resource, and the protocol version in use.

```
    Request       = Request-Line              ; Section 5.1
                    *(( general-header        ; Section 4.5
                     | request-header         ; Section 5.3
                     | entity-header ) CRLF)  ; Section 7.1
                    CRLF
                    [ message-body ]          ; Section 4.3
```

A header section you provide, and body is something you want to have as empty string. However, you need to anyway have CRLF in place, so request would look something like this:

```
POST /url HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, application/javascript, text/javascript
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_112)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

or, to put [CRLF] on where that character is,

```
POST /url HTTP/1.1[CRLF]
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[CRLF]
Accept: application/json, application/javascript, text/javascript[CRLF]
Content-Length: 0[CRLF]
Host: localhost:8888[CRLF]
Connection: Keep-Alive[CRLF]
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_112)[CRLF]
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[CRLF]
[CRLF]
```

Since the content-length is zero and the CRLF separator needs to always be there, how would you tell a difference between empty string sent as body and no body sent at all? The thing is you can't, in this context it's the same thing, so what you ask can't be done.